# image_compressed problem in rqt_image_view

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i'am logging jpeg compressed image in a bag and i can see these images when using rqt_bag. When i try to do live viewing of the image using rqt_image_view (topic played from the bag), the player fails to load the transport  image_compressed withe the following error :

**Unable to load plugin for transport 'image_compressed', error string:
According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/image_compressed_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/compressedDepth_sub image_transport/compressed_sub image_transport/raw_sub image_transport/theora_sub**

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245836/image_compressed-problem-in-rqt_image_view/) by [jpiat](https://answers.ros.org/users/28270/jpiat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2018-08-01**:
I got the same error. For me the fix was to end the topic name with "/compressed", i.e `/camera/image_raw/compressed`. I had it like: `/camera/image_compressed` and it was giving me that error.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-10-03**:
tanasis, please post a new question. You are not supposed to write "compressed", so there is something wrong in your setup, Also check [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/compressed_image_transport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing [compressed_image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/compressed_image_transport) in your ros installation.

Yes, this question is a little old, but is first hit on google for this error...

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on 2021-08-17**:
This worked for me